# Count number of occurences of specific number in numpy arrary in Excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, numpy

```
import numpy as np

from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

x1 = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)

for i in range(0,sheet_1.max_row):

    x1[i]=sheet_1.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value

x2[i] = np.count_nonzero(x1[i])
collections.Counter(x2[i])[0]
```

I wanted to count the number of occurrence of 0 in the same column and add them up and find out the total number of element in the excel sheet.so the results expecting should be 3.It seems that numpy is unable to count. I have tried sum but it only adds up the element in the array. Appreciate any help from you guys.

Error Message: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Excel sheet:
5
5
3
3
4
5
5
0
0
0

Comment: if you want to count the number of zeros in a numpy array, just use `arr.size - np.count_nonzero(arr)` making sure to take care of issues with the shape of the array.

Comment: Two things: 1- could you add the **complete** traceback (to be more precise here we need the line number of the error). 2- Is your data integers only ? If so you should cast the array to np.int type because **direct float comparison are not reliable** (3.0*1.1!=3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward numpy-only solution to the *"counting occurence of a specific number in a numpy array"* question would be this:

```
# Note that I cast x1 to np.int because "arr==x" is not reliable with floats
x1=np.array([5,5,3,3,4,5,5,0,0,0],dtype=np.int)

#(x1==0) is boolean array that is True only where 0s are.
#summing that array gives the count of 0s
count_0=np.sum(x1==0)
count_5=np.sum(x1==5)

print("# of 0 : ",count_0)
print("# of 5 : ",count_5)
```

Output :

```
# of 0 :  3
# of 5 :  4
```

**An other solution (the one you where seemingly trying implement)** using `Counter` would read :

```
count=collections.Counter(x1)
print("# of 0 : ",count[0])
print("# of 5 : ",count[5])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Didn't know that dtype could be used to change from float to int. Thanks a lot.